# New classification method in machine learning python code optimization

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, classification

I've new method of classification. I've developed it in python. But code is very slow.

Please, help me to optimize code below.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from datetime import datetime
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
import copy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

This function for finding hyperspheres in space

```
def find_sphere(ind, df, dist_sq, sidx):
    objectCount = df.shape[0]
    sphere = dict()
    sphere['index'] = ind
    sphere['relatives'] = []
    sphere['class'] = df.at[ind, "Class"]
    indexes = sidx[:, ind]
    sphere['distances'] = dist_sq[ind, :]
    for i in range(objectCount):
        if df.at[ind, "Class"] != df.at[indexes[i], "Class"]:
            sphere['relatives'] = indexes[:i]
            sphere['radius'] = sphere['distances'][indexes[i]]
            break
    sphere['enemies'] = np.where(
        sphere['distances'] == sphere['radius'])[0]
    sphere['coverages'] = set()
    for enemy in sphere['enemies']:
        min_dist = dist_sq[enemy, sphere['relatives']].min()
        sphere['coverages'].update(
            sphere['relatives'][np.where(dist_sq[enemy, sphere['relatives']] == min_dist)[0]])
    sphere['relatives'] = set(sphere['relatives'])
    return sphere
```

This function is clustering objects in space

```
def find_groups(spheres):
    coverages = {x for d in spheres for x in d['coverages']}
    all_coverages = {x for d in spheres for x in d['coverages']}
    notSeenObjects = copy.deepcopy(spheres)

    groups = list()
    while (len(coverages) > 0):
        # print(f'\t getting one of {len(coverages)} coverage(s)...')
        obj = coverages.pop()
        group = {d['index'] for d in notSeenObjects if obj in d['relatives']}
        if len(group) == 0:
            continue
        linkerCoverage = set()
        while True:
            linkerCoverage = linkerCoverage | {r for s in notSeenObjects if s['index'] in group
                                               for r in s['relatives'] if r in all_coverages}

            notSeenObjects = [
                s for s in notSeenObjects if not s['index'] in group]

            newObjects = {s['index'] for s in notSeenObjects if len(
                s['relatives'].intersection(linkerCoverage)) > 0}

            if len(newObjects) == 0:
                break

            group = group | newObjects
            coverages = coverages - linkerCoverage
        groups.append(group)
    return groups
```

This function finding all standart objects. Means, new objects can be classified with this (standart) objects instead of seeing of all objects

```
def find_standart_objects(spheres, dists, groups):
    standartObjects = [(s['index'], s['radius'], s['class']) for s in spheres]
    for group in sorted(groups, key=len, reverse=True):
        candidates = [s for s in standartObjects if s[0] in group]
        for candidate in sorted(candidates, key=lambda x: x[1]):
            isRightRecognition = True
            for obj in spheres:
                result = sorted([(dists[obj['index'], s[0]] / s[1], obj['class'], s[2])
                                 for s in standartObjects if s[0] != candidate[0]], key=lambda x: x[0])
                mindist = result[0][0]
                for r in result:
                    if r[0] != mindist:
                        break
                    isRightRecognition = isRightRecognition and r[1] == r[2]
                if not isRightRecognition:
                    print(f'Standart found {candidate[0]}')
                    break
            if isRightRecognition:
                standartObjects = [
                    s for s in standartObjects if s[0] != candidate[0]]
    return standartObjects
```

This part is using that functions

```
df = pd.read_csv("Dry_Bean.txt", sep='\t') #https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00602/DryBeanDataset.zip
objectCount = df.shape[0]
dist_sq = euclidean_distances(df.iloc[:, :-1]).round(15)
sidx = np.argsort(dist_sq, axis=0)
spheres = Parallel(n_jobs=6)(delayed(find_sphere)
                             (ind, df, dist_sq, sidx) for ind in range(0, objectCount))
groups = find_groups(spheres)
standartObjects = find_standart_objects(spheres, dist_sq, groups)
```

Bottle neck parts are find_standart_objects and find_sphere functions.

Comment: Have you run a profiler on your code to see where it's spending its time?

Comment: No but debugging shows that result = sorted([(dists[obj['index'], s[0]] / s[1], obj['class'], s[2]) for s in standartObjects if s[0] != candidate[0]], key=lambda x: x[0]) part runs slow

Comment: Well, for one it looks like there's no reason to sort everything in the inner loop. You could move it to the very top of the function, outside the loops, and just do the filtering `if s[0] != candidate[0]` within the loop...

Comment: no result should be sorted by first element of tuple.

Comment: Ah, true. My bad...